# Convert multiple GeoTIFF to one KMZ

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, kmz, gdal-translate, superoverlay

I am using GDAL to convert GeoTIFF to KMZ. I am using the following command:

```
gdal_translate.exe -of KMLSUPEROVERLAY *.tif out.kmz
```

If I have one TIF file in the folder, it works ok. If I have more than one, then I receive the following error:

```
FAILURE: Too many command options.
```

How can I run the `gdal_translate.exe` command to combine more than one `TIF` file into one `KMZ` file?

Answer (score 3):

If you have more than one `GeoTIFF`, you can mosaic them before the conversion. For instance, you can make a virtual mosaic from all of them contained in the same directory:

```
gdalbuildvrt mosaic.vrt *.tif
gdal_translate -of KMLSUPEROVERLAY mosaic.vrt out.kmz
```